# OS seems to forget my second monitor

Tags: linux-mint, hardware, multi-monitor

I use a dual-monitor setup with Acer H233H as one of the monitors and the same problem keeps happening.

During the installation of Linux (both Arch and Mint), both monitors work fine. They also work on the first run, but after that, OS stops detecting my Acer monitor. Sometimes, it just detects it as "DP-3", sometimes correctly as Acer but with wrong resolutions. In both cases, there's simply no output to that monitor.

Even when I leave that monitor as the only one, same thing, "no signal".

What's going on?

[Here's](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?probe=532b72754e) the log dump.